# Find the $f$ of $g$ where $f(x) =x^2+2x+1$ and $g(x)=2x-3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

According to my textbook the $f$ of $g$ where $f(x) =x^2+2x+1$ and $g(x)=2x-3$  is $4x^2-8x+2$, but I get $4x^2-8x+4$.

What am I doing wrong?

**My Steps:**

$(2x-3)^2 + 2(2x-3)+1$

$(2x-3)(2x-3)+4x-6+1$

$4x^2-12x+9+4x-6+1$

$4x^2-8x+4$

Comment: You are not wrong, the textbook seems to be incorrect

Comment: @PeterForeman Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: I've double checked your math. It's all correct. Your textbook must be wrong

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach to your calculation is to factor $f$ first:
$$f(x) = x^2 + 2x + 1 = (x+1)^2.$$
Then, $$f(g(x)) = (g(x)+1)^2 = ((2x-3)+1)^2 = (2x-2)^2 = 2^2(x-1)^2 = 4x^2 - 8x + 4.$$

To check that the book's solution cannot be correct, it suffices to choose $x = 0$, which leads to $g(0) = -3$, and $$f(g(0)) = f(-3) = (-3)^2 + 2(-3) + 1 = 9 - 6 + 1 = 4.$$  Your computation is consistent with this result, since $$4(0)^2 - 8(0) + 4 = 4,$$ but the book's solution is not, since it gives $2$ when $x = 0$.